# UTF-8 : characters not recognized

Tags: java, parsing, utf-8, hashmap

I am trying to parse a text file using HashMap. The problem is that I have special characters like Ș and Ț and my application didn't recognize them.
This is my code:

```
    Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
      fin = new FileInputStream("inferredflexforms.txt");
      isr = new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-8");
      br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String line = br.readLine();
      while (line != null) {

        String[] toks = line.split("\\s+");
        m.put(toks[0], toks[1]);
        line = br.readLine();
      }
    } finally {
      if (br != null)  { br.close();  }
      if (isr != null) { isr.close(); }
      if (fin != null) { fin.close(); }
    }

System.out.println(m);
```

My text file contains: dănțaseși    dansa

And my output is: dăn?ase?i=dansa

The "ș" and "ț" was replaced by "?". 
What should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: The problem isn't that your *application* isn't recognizing them; either the terminal that's printing the output or the font it's using just doesn't have the Unicode support for the characters. If you write `m` out to another file, you should be able to open it in a compliant editor and see the correct output.

Comment: @chrylis I use eclipse and I edited the text file using the text editor from eclipse and the default font. And characters like "ă", "â", "î" are parsed corectly. If i write the line System.out.println("țȚȘ"); the console output is correct...

Comment: What happens if you print the output yourself instead of using the default `LinkedHashMap#toString()`?

Comment: Are you sure the input file contains UTF8?

Comment: @JB Nizet If the charaters "Ș" and "Ț" are not UTF-8 format then what format should i use?

Comment: @chrylis System.out.print("dănțaseși"); return the output dănțaseși, not dăn?ase?i. I don't think is a problem with the console

Comment: UTF8 is one of many ways to represent unicode characters as bytes. If the encoding used to write the file was UTF16, or any other encoding supporting these characters, then reading it as UTF8 won't lead to the correct result. Try writing a file containing those chars, using UTF8, and read it again, still using UTF8. That should obviously work. And compare the bytes in the file you wrote with the file that you're trying to read.

Comment: I run the program again and now it works...i guess eclipse is trying to be funny... Thank you both for helping me!